# Plot two size vector length with xyplot

Tags: r, plot, lattice, linear-interpolation

Please note that this is a simplified version (and therefore duplicate of my earlier post):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358694/xyplot-2-separate-data-frame-lengths

It may well be that it contained too much information, however quite basic was asked.

So here again:

I would like to plot 2 columns of different length with xyplot (only xyplot please).

The data:

```
Data <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(10,0,1),prob=seq(0.023,0.365,length=10))
Long <- data.frame(var2=rnorm(20,2,3))
```

How I would plot the Long (var2) vector of length 20 onto the plot of "Data" where (prob~var1) is plotted first.

Comment: Why not edit your previous question? Or wait a little longer for an answer? Your previous question is only 2 hours old.

Comment: @ialm. Yes, this is why I'm keeping the longer version, also as reference in case. Sure only 2 hours, but saw elsewhere that shorter question maybe preferable to answer by some.

Comment: Do you have a `prob2` variable to go with `var2` in `Long`?

Comment: @Max you need `x` values and `y` values in order to plot. What do you want the `y` values to be for `Long`?

Comment: If you click on the link above the posted question, it explains how I went onto creating the "y". Basically that's the point. I would like to plot it against the prob, but that's too short.

Comment: So is the basic issue that you need to determine a value for "prob" for each value of long?

Comment: @John. Yes. So that the Long can be ploted against the new "prob". (since you plot y~x, with xyplot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `approx()` inside your call to xyplot to interpolate the values of `Data$prob` after passing `Long$var2` as a separate variable in the call. Notice the custom prepanel plot to adjust the limits.

```
lattice::xyplot(prob ~ var1, data = Data, z = Long$var2,
                xlab = "Var1, Var2",
                prepanel = function(x, y, z, ...) {
                  list(xlim = range(x, z),
                       ylim = range(y))
                },
                panel = function(x, y, z, ...) {
                  b <- approx(y, n = length(z))$y
                  panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
                  panel.xyplot(z, b, col = "orange", ...)
                })
```

[image: Imgur]

**EDIT:** Actually, it is much cleaner to just reshape the data first.

```
dd <- rbind(data.frame(var = "var1",
                       val = Data$var1,
                       prob = Data$prob),
            data.frame(var = "var2",
                       val = Long$var2,
                       prob = approx(Data$prob, n = 20)$y))

xyplot(prob ~ val, data = dd, groups = var, auto.key = TRUE)
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: thanks, I will check this up once I have a bit of time.